# Compare 2 .csv files

Tags: powershell, csv, compare

I have two .csv files with many information in it. If at the end of the sentence is a "M", I have to look if this row is in the other file. When it's there I have to look if the code at the beggining of the row is the same, when not then I have to do nothing, but when it's the same I have to make a new file.

This is the information I have to look if it's in the other file:

[image: Screenshot 1]

You can see that the information is here:

[image: Screenshot 2]

I also have rows with a "B" at the end but this is unimportant:

[image: Screenshot 3]

Now, when the information is here, I have to export all rows that are same in both files.

I have to export the rows in a new file which have the same code at the beginning which is circeld in red:

[image: Screenshot 4]

I have tried different solutions that I looked up in the Internet, but nothing really works.

Perhaps something like this?

```
$datenbank = Import-Csv "C:\Users\information1.csv"
$zentral = Import-Csv "C:\Users\information2.csv"
$new = ""

foreach ($line in $datenbank) {
    $Spalte = $line.Split(",")
    foreach ($z in $Zentral) {
        $found = $false
        foreach ($d in $Datenbanktyp) {
            if ($d.$Spalte[1] -eq $z.$Spalte[1]) {
                $found = $true
            }
        }
        if ($found -eq $true) {
            $new += $z
        }
    }
}
```

Or can it work with a `if..elseif..else` loop?

Comment: Why do you use Import-Csv and then line.Split(";")? Import-Csv does the line split for you.

Comment: You also use $z as a top-level variable and a counter in a foreach.

Comment: You're using variables you never assigned `$dbtyp` vs. `$datenbank` and `$z` vs. `$Zentral`.  You might take a look to the cmdlet [Compare-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-5.1) .... it's designed to compare objects.  ;-)

Comment: @PalleDue I made an script before and there I had to add line.Split(“,”). So I did it here. & I have this script from a other forum where someone had a similar problem like mine.

Comment: @Olaf I had the same variables and it didn’t work. I changed it, forgot to change it back & made the screenshot, sorry!

Comment: @PalleDue I don’t know what you mean?

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve]. I would also recommend including more complete examples of your input CSVs as well as an example of the desired output (sensitive information may be obfuscated, but we need to know the structure of your data). The example should demonstrate both what should and what shouldn't be exported. Also, you said that you need to compare the beginning of the rows, but your screenshots compare columns towards the end, and with a partial match no less. Please clarify what you want to match against what, and what you want to do with matching lines.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I have edited my question. I hope it's better to understand!

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I got this right. You have one file where the second-last column contains a letter. If that letter is "M" you want to check if the value of the column before that (partially) matches a column from a second file. If it does, you then want to export all rows from the second file that have the same value in the first column as the matched row to a new file.

Since you didn't reveal the column names I'm going to dub the third- and second-last columns from the first file "Erin" and "Marty", the match column from the second file "Pat", and the first column from the second file "Gene".

```
$datenbank | Where-Object {
    $_.Marty -ceq 'M'
} | Select-Object -Expand Erin -Unique | ForEach-Object {
    $outfile  = "export_${_}.csv"  # adjust output filename as you see fit
    $firstcol = $zentral |
                Where { $_.Pat -like "*${_}*" } |
                Select-Object -Expand Gene
    $zentral | Where-Object {
        $_.Gene -eq $firstcol
    } | Export-Csv $outfile
}
```

Another approach would be to group your second file by the first column and then check if the groups contain a matching value.

```
$groups = $zentral | Group-Object Gene

$datenbank | Where-Object {
    $_.Marty -ceq 'M'
} | Select-Object -Expand Erin -Unique | ForEach-Object {
    $outfile  = "export_${_}.csv"  # adjust output filename as you see fit
    $groups | Where-Object {
        $_.Group.Pat -like "*${_}*"
    } | Select-Object -Expand Group | Export-Csv $outfile
}
```

Replace *"Erin"*, *"Marty"*, *"Pat"* and *"Gene"* with the actual column titles from your CSV files. Should your files not contain column titles you need to specify them via the `-Header` parameter of `Import-Csv`, otherwise the cmdlet will interpret the first data row as the headers.

Comment: The columns don’t have any names, but I thank you very very much! This is so helpful!

Comment: @MaggieRosskopf If the CSVs don't have column titles you need to specify column titles via the `-Header` parameter, otherwise `Import-Csv` will interpret the first data row as the column headers. That's why your attempt didn't work. You need to specify column headers and replace "Marty", "Erin", "Pat" and "Gene" with the correct header names.